# Private fields with sql query

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I recently changed my queries on the SQL database from

```
Model.findOne().populate("Model2").exec(function(err, result) {
})
```

to :

```
Model.query(sqlQuery, parameters, function(err, result) {
})
```

The reason I changed the queries are performances problems : it goes much faster using the second way than the first one (when you join tables).

My question is the following : Using the Waterline syntax, I was able to retrieve only the elements I wanted (elements defined in the model), but using the query method ("Select * from model ...") gives me the result I ask to the database, but I'd like to be able to filter the fields that are defined in my model. Is that possible?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model definitions are on the `sails.models.MODEL` object.

You could reference the available attributes there.

```
Object.keys(sails.models.MODEL._attributes).join(',')
```